# Make an element take several columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

If I understand correctly the command "grid-column: span 2" allows an element to take several columns, but I have a strange bug in the following case:
[image]

I don't understand why my first div (i1) red doesn't appear, it should take the first line, like the yellow div (i4)

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 80% 10%;
}

#i1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

#i2 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#i3 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 2/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#i4 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/3;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="i1"></div>
  <div id="i2"></div>
  <div id="i3"></div>
  <div id="i4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put an X in your red column and see where it is put

Answer (score 1):

in #id1 i have removed the :-
grid-column: 1/2;
grid-row: 1/3;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Css/style.css">

    <style>
        #container
{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display : grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
    grid-template-rows : 10% 80% 10%;
}

#i1
{
    background-color: red;
    grid-column: span 2;  

}
#i2
{
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}
#i3
{
    background-color: green;
    grid-column: 2/2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}
#i4
{
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/3;
    background-color: yellow;
    grid-column: span 2;  
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="i1"></div>
        <div id="i2"></div>
        <div id="i3"></div>
        <div id="i4"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see that it works, but I don't really understand why it doesn't work for me, and I would like to understand so that I can progress, do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing grid-column: 1/ span 2 and it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yours was not working because you set `grid-column: span 2;` for `#i1` which basically overrides your `grid-column: 1/2;`. And `grid-column: span 2;` is shorthand for :

```
 grid-column-start: span 2;
 grid-column-end: auto;
```

mixed with  `grid-row: 1/3;` when you only need `grid-row: 1/2;`which caused the problem. As a matter of fact even for your `#i4` there were mistakes.

Your problem should have less to do with why this happening and more to do with correcting the properties because many time some properties give unexpected result favorable or not, so better take care to follow guidelines and correct syntax and not fall in such unexpected situations.

> The **grid-column** property specifies a grid item's size and location in
> a grid layout, and is a shorthand property for the following
> properties:
>
> - grid-column-start
> - grid-column-end
>
> The **grid-row** property specifies a grid item's size and location in a
> grid layout, and is a shorthand property for the following
> properties::
>
> - grid-row-start
> - grid-row-end

```css
#container {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 80% 10%;
  /*gap:10px;*/
}

#i1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: red;

}

#i2 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#i3 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 2/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#i4 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="i1"></div>
  <div id="i2"></div>
  <div id="i3"></div>
  <div id="i4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Twyy see this link https://cssreference.io/property/grid-column/

Comment: Why does it work on my last line when I do the same thing?